# cs50 return gives wrong value

Tags: c, cs50

When I run this code I expect the return give me (100-percent)/100 - price

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>

float discount(int prec , float pri);

int main (void){
  int percent = get_float("enter the present here ");
  float price =  get_float("enter the price ");
  float function1 = discount(percent , price);
  printf("the new number is %.2f\n", function1);
}

float discount(int prec , float pri){
    return (100 - prec)/100 * pri ;
}
```

but I got this return and I don't know what the problem is

```
$ make lesson
$ ./lesson
enter the present here 15
enter the price 100
the new number is 0.00
```

when I use this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>

float discount(int prec , float pri);

int main (void){
  int percent = get_float("enter the present here ");
  float price =  get_float("enter the price ");
  float function1 = discount(percent , price);
  printf("the new number is %.2f\n", function1);
}

float discount(int prec , float pri){
    return pri * (100 - prec)/100 ;
}
```

I got the correct value but I want to know why the first example didn't work

```
$ make lesson
$ ./lesson
enter the present here 14
enter the price 100
the new number is 86.00
```

Comment: `(100 - prec) / 100` is done as integer arithmetic and produces zero.

Comment: use `(100 - (float)prec)/100 * pri` or `(100f - prec)/100f * pri`, force the calculation to use floats by casting `prec` to float or to use float constants